# Modelling the Z mass

Tags: quantum-field-theory, particle-physics, standard-model, statistics

I'm interested in approximating (analytically) the mass distribution of the Z boson, as shown below (numerically/MC):

[image: CMS]

On-shell, you obviously have a Breit-Wigner distribution; but what about to the left- and right- hand sides of the peak? Are there any obvious choices of functions to use to write down something like

$$f_{\mathrm{on-shell}}\times BW(m_Z,\Gamma_Z)+f_{\mathrm{off-shell}}\times\ldots ?$$

where the $f$'s would be the fraction of on/off-shell events generated with MC?

Since there are direct connections with the bosons' propagators, you could maybe describe the left-hand side $\propto 1/M(\ell\ell)^2$, but that doesn't seem to apply to the right-hand side.

Suggestions?

Comment: By "left- and right- hand sides of the peak", are you actually asking about modelling the background?

Comment: I'm asking about the $\gamma$ and $Z^*$ interference terms, no other background

Answer (score 1):

On shell means "on the rest mass", so it is one number, not  a distribution.

The  Breit-Wigner is a distribution that has wings,but look at the published by the experiments [width of the Z boson](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/W_and_Z_bosons) :

Z: $2.4952±0.0023 GeV/c2$

This is the width of the calculated  Breit-Wigner distribution. If one compares it with the width in the plot, it is obvious that it is the experimental errors that dominate the shape.

The  Breit-Wigner has to be folded with the statistical error distribution which dominates, and this is  evaluated by [monte carlo](http://home.thep.lu.se/~torbjorn/talks/cern12a.pdf)  which has all the errors coming from the indeterminacy of the detectors and the systematics too. That is how the value of ~2.5 GeV for the signal was unfolded.

At the level you are talking , you could use a Gaussian distribution to fit the curve, folding it over a falling background. You will have a fit , but just a width for the experimental errors, not the width of the Z decay.

Comment: Thanks for the details! Actually, on/off-shell is an abuse of language in the MC generator sense: "on" describes the production of a Z in a small mass window around the true $m(Z)$ - that is, a Breit-Wigner with a larger (folded) width than $\Gamma(Z)$ - and "off" describes the $\gamma$ and $Z/\gamma$ interference terms, which behave more or less as in the plot I pasted in my question (smoothly falling from low values (MC cut to avoid singularity) to $m(Z)$, then picking up a bit in a way that $1/m(\ell\ell)$ doesn't describe accurately anymore.